# Can globals be localized?

Tags: localization, globals

In the multi-lingual site I'm building, I've created an "SEO" global set where my client can enter keywords and a description to populate meta tags site-wide.

Problem: globals don't seem to be translatable.

So unless I'm missing something, I'll have to add additional dedicated fields to hold the Spanish version of this info.

Am I missing something? How would you approach this, if you'd do it differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, globals can be localised. Make sure you have ticked **"This field is translatable"** in the field settings for the ones in your global set, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jamie. It turns out I'm a dolt. I had that field setting checked, but when I went back to look at the "Globals" section in the control panel, I didn't notice that for these, the locale switcher is at the top of the page next to the "Globals" title. I'd even already filled in spanish versions for these, but forgot I'd done it. I'm going to mark yours as the correct answer and paste a screenshot below.

Answer (score 4):

Per my comment on Jamie's answer above, I didn't notice that on the Globals section in the control panel, the locale switcher is up where the version switcher usually is on entries:

[image]

One of those UI-blindness moments.